# Using filter beside query_string in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, full-text-search

How to full text search and have filter? I want to search for a text among documents with `language_id=10`. I've tried it this way:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Declared"
    },
    {
      "filtered": {
        "filter": {
          "term": {
            "language_id": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but seems like it's not correct. How to correct it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yep, the syntax of the filtered query is a bit cumbersome. AFAIK it should look like that:

```json
{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "query":{
            "query_string":{
               "query":"Declared"
            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "term":{
               "language_id":10
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried your format but it doesn't work, the filters are working better in the format of @Kévin 's answer. Please have a look

Comment: Ah that was a typo, fixed

Answer (score 15):

In version 5.2, filtered query is replaced by the bool query, and returns error on my Elastic 5.2 instance. See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/query-dsl-filtered-query.html).

The new syntax is:

```json
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "query_string":{
               "query":"Declared"
            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "term":{
               "language_id":10
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Validated on ES 6.7.2

Answer (score 4):

Sorry Ashalynd but the filter is not placed a the right place in your answer.

This is working better:

```
{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "query":{
            "query_string":{
               "query":"Declared"
            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "term":{
               "language_id":10
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: it is this which works and not the one mentioned by @Ashalynd .. Was a big help thanks!